# JQuery DataTables Server-Side Processing Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am trying to implement DataTables using server-sided processing.

As far as I can tell, what I have is correct.. however when I load the page, all I see is `"No matching records found"`.

I am using  DataTables 1.10.9.

My table is set up like this:

```
<table id="resellerListTable" class="table table-hover table-condensed display dataTable no-footer" role="grid">
    <thead>
    <tr role="row">
        <th class="sorting_disabled" name="asd"></th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled">Name</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled">Active</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled no-sort"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr role="row">
        <th class="sorting_disabled" name="asd"></th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled">Name</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled">Active</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled no-sort"></th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

This is the Javascript initialising the DataTable.

```
$('#resellerListTable').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        type: 'POST',
        url: self.ajaxRoute,
        data: function (d) {
            // Format DataTables data for the API, and include some required data.
            var returnData = {
                controller: controller,
                method: method,
                data: d,
            };
            window.$.extend(returnData.data, data);
            return JSON.stringify(returnData);
        },
        dataSrc: function (d) {
            // Format API response for DataTables
            var response = d;
            if (typeof d.response != 'undefined') {
                response = d.response;
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response)); // Output from this is below...
            return response;
        },
        async: true,
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
        drawCallback: function() {
            console.log('table drawn');
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the output logged from the above `console.log()`

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "<img src='' />",
            "Something 1",
            "not active",
            "<a href='/retailer/edit/1'>Edit</a><a href='/retailer/delete/1'>Delete</a>"
        ],
        [
            "<img src='' />",
            "Something 2",
            "not active",
            "<a href='/retailer/edit/2'>Edit</a><a href='/retailer/delete/2'>Delete</a>"
        ],
        [
            "<img src='' />",
            "Something 3",
            "not active",
            "<a href='/retailer/edit/3'>Edit</a><a href='/retailer/delete/3'>Delete</a>"
        ],
        [
            "<img src='' />",
            "Something 4",
            "not active",
            "<a href='/retailer/edit/4'>Edit</a><a href='/retailer/delete/4'>Delete</a>"
        ],
        [
            "<img src='' />",
            "Something 5",
            "not active",
            "<a href='/retailer/edit/5'>Edit</a><a href='/retailer/delete/5'>Delete</a>"
        ],
        [
            "<img src='' />",
            "Something 6",
            "not active",
            "<a href='/retailer/edit/6'>Edit</a><a href='/retailer/delete/6'>Delete</a>"
        ],
        [
            "<img src='' />",
            "Something 7",
            "not active",
            "<a href='/retailer/edit/7'>Edit</a><a href='/retailer/delete/7'>Delete</a>"
        ],
        [
            "<img src='' />",
            "Something 8",
            "not active",
            "<a href='/retailer/edit/8'>Edit</a><a href='/retailer/delete/8'>Delete</a>"
        ],
        [
            "<img src='' />",
            "Something 9",
            "not active",
            "<a href='/retailer/edit/9'>Edit</a><a href='/retailer/delete/9'>Delete</a>"
        ],
        [
            "<img src='' />",
            "Something 10",
            "not active",
            "<a href='/retailer/edit/10'>Edit</a><a href='/retailer/delete/10'>Delete</a>"
        ]
    ],
    "recordsTotal": "23",
    "recordsFiltered": "23",
    "draw": 1
}
```

I can also tell that DataTables is trying to draw the results as `table drawn` is being output in the console after every refresh.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: in the datasrc callback try `return response.data;` instead of `return response;` as per the example here https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc

Comment: also I think the item inside the "data" in the JSON should be objects, not arrays. i.e. `"data": [
        {
            "<img src='' />",
            "Something 1",
            "not active",
            "<a href='/retailer/edit/1'>Edit</a><a href='/retailer/delete/1'>Delete</a>"
        }` Note the {...} denoting an object instead of [...] denoting an array. And each item in the object should have a property name denoting the column it belongs to, e,g. `"column1": "<img src='' />"`. See https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Both of those changes seem to have fixed my problem with seeing the rows in the table. However, the result count is off. I am seeing "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from NaN total entries)" rather than the expected "Showing 1 to 10 of 23 entries (filtered from NaN total entries)". Is there another function I should be adding to format the response when DataTables is looking for that data?

Comment: since you've set the "server-side" option, your response needs to be returning the parameters shown in the link here. https://datatables.net/manual/server-side This is because you're supposed to be handling all the paging etc. logic on the server. P.S. I've never used DataTables, all I'm doing is reading the manual - maybe you need to study it in a bit more depth before you carry on

Comment: I am returning those parameters from the API, with the exception that the required information is inside a `response` property in the returned data. This is why I was manipulating the dataSrc function as above. However it seems that is purely for the actual data, and not the additional parameters.

Comment: I fixed it by adjusting the data in `dataSrc`, and passing it by reference. @ADyson post your initial response as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

1) In the `dataSrc` callback put

```
return response.data;
```

instead of

```
return response;
```

as per the example at https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc

2) I think the item inside the "data" in the JSON should be objects, not arrays, i.e.

```
"data": [ { "<img src='' />", "Something 1", "not active", "<a href='/retailer/edit/1'>Edit</a><a href='/retailer/delete/1'>Delete</a>" }...
```

Note the {...} denoting an object instead of [...] denoting an array. And each item in the object should have a property name denoting the column it belongs to, e,g.

```
"column1": "<img src='' />"
```

See https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html

Comment: I ended up doing the following, so as the response was modified by reference: `dataSrc: function (d) {
                d.draw = d.response.draw;
                d.recordsTotal = d.response.recordsTotal;
                d.recordsFiltered = d.response.recordsFiltered;
                return d.response.data;
            }`

Comment: yes that will work. Although if you are able to modify the server's response, it would make more sense to just return them in the right structure from there, then you wouldn't have to modify it in the JS.